# vgscan not finding groups after an unexpected reboot

Tags: lvm

I have an LVM partition on one of my disks:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007b303

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   976773167   488386552+  8e  Linux LVM
```

After a clean reboot of my system, the volume group did not show up. I tried running vgscan, but that did not find any volume groups:

```
root@luxembourg:~# vgscan --ignorelockingfailure --mknodes
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  No volume groups found
  No volume groups found
```

Also, pvs does not find a physical volume on my LVM partition:

```
root@luxembourg:~# pvs /dev/sdb1
  No physical volume label read from /dev/sdb1
  Failed to read physical volume "/dev/sdb1"
```

What happened with my LVM volumes? Could that be related to the reboot? How can I recover them?